# How can I use recursion to find increments of a number in python?

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following code, but it just doesn't work when I run it. I would like it to return something like: [5,10,15,20] if the inputed value for n is 4. Any advice is very appreciated.

```
def MultipleRecursive(n):
    multiples=[]
    if n==0:
        multiples.append(n)
    else:
        Total=5*MultipleRecursive(n-1)
        multiples.append(Total)
    return multiples
```

Comment: for one, your indentation is wrong

Comment: then, `MultipleRecursive` returns a list. 5*list is 5 lists. then, your example output does not contain any `0`, yet, you append `0`(n when n == 0) to your result.

Comment: Any particular reason to use recursion here? The easiest solution for what you have is something like `[5*i for i in range(1, n+1)]`

Comment: Yeah I'm doing a project where we do the same problems using Iteration and Recursion. I got the one using Iteration, but I'm having trouble manipulating a list with recursion.

Answer (score 3):

A trivial version is:

```
def mr(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    return mr(n-1) + [5*n]
```

Comment: Ok I just modified it to include an else statement and an empty list defined above the conditionals. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def rek(n):
    list = []
    if n == 0:
        return list
    else:
        list = rek(n-1)
        list.append(5*n)
        return list

print rek(4)
>>> [5, 10, 15, 20]
```

Comment: This works really well and helps me a lot in making sense of the situation. Is there any way to have n be the only parameter and define a blank list within the function to manipulate? Thanks!

Comment: you do realize that you could reverse 2 lines and not have to sort, right (in which case, you don't really need to pass the list at all, since it would be empty anyway)? also, you can define a default value for `list` and not need to  pass an empty list in the first call.

Comment: sorry, haven't been around my laptop for a few days, here are changes.